# Can I stop KDE from making a copy of a file I just overwrote?

Tags: kubuntu, kde

Let' say I overwrite a text file named `test.txt` in KDE. KDE will make a copy of the old file and save it as `test.txt~` in the same directory.

Is it possible to disable that? I make copies of the old files I need, so it's highly annoying to have every file in two versions.

Comment: That's not KDE doing that, it's whichever editor you are using.  Please add information about which app you are using to edit the files.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can disable this by opening your editor of text, then go to preferences and disable automatic backup.

If you are using kedit, then go to settings > configure > disable backups when saving text.